# RTNETLINK answers: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: linux, networking, network-adapter, network-interface

I have a simple XDP program and I want to load it on an interface. I'm on `Ubuntu 18.04` with kernel version of `5.6.3-050603-lowlatency` which supports XDP. My NIC is `Intel 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+` which also supports XDP and my NIC driver is `ixgbe 5.1.0-k`.

When I run the following command to load XDP using `xdpdrv` in native mode I get the following error:

```
$ sudo ip link set dev ens1f0 xdpdrv obj xdp.o sec .text
RTNETLINK answers: Cannot allocate memory
```

But loading it in `xdpgeneric` mode works just fine:

```
$ sudo ip link set dev ens1f0 xdpgeneric obj xdp.o sec .text
$ ip link show ens1f0
4: ens1f0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP> mtu 1450 xdpgeneric qdisc mq master bond0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1b:21:bc:8f:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    prog/xdp id 5991
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/facebookincubator/katran/issues/84